# It looks like IE does not have canvas

Tags: html

I would like to implement a simple drawing tool that could run across most of the browsers, but it's not working on IE. Any one have an idea on how can I achieve maximum browser compatibility?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use the HTML5 canvas element in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie)

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 is the first version to support the canvas element.  Support seems pretty complete and my rendering experiments have been consistent with Chrome and FireFox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explorer canvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) to support canvas element in Internet Explorer (including IE6)

To use it, just add this to your document:

```
<head>
<!--[if IE]><script src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Further instructions (for specific versions) are [here](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). VML on IE and SVG on other browsers. They claim:

> Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.