# html5 canvas doesn't work in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, canvas, progress-bar

I have built this progress bar in html5. 
The bar is clickable and you get an explanaion when you click on each of the sections.
It works but not in IE8. 
Can anyone tell me what is worng? I have been working on it for a month but nothing!!
a little help pls. :-)

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie

Comment: I don't get it, why isn't it working here [link]http://s-maof.com/simulator/index1.php?fkapp=1#undefined . I have looked in the other question and still nothing..

Answer (score 10):

IE8 doesn't support canvas natively. You can use [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas) to add canvas functionality to IE8.

All you have to do is include the `excanvas.js` file in your page.

Example from the [explorercanvas wiki](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions):

```
<head>
<!--[if IE]><script src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
```