# How to get awesomeCloud working with IE8

Tags: jquery, html

I am using [awesomeCloud](http://indyarmy.com/awesomeCloud/) is a word cloud plugin for jQuery.

It uses the HTML Canvas element, however this is not supported by IE8.

What can I do to get it to run on IE8?

Comment: Upgrade to IE9 or use a different Browser. You can also file an enhancement request at Microsoft.

Comment: Enhancement request????? Pahahahahaha

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use the HTML5 canvas element in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Views on IE aside, take a look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) gives browsers a way to detect if it has any basic support for html5 components and if not gives you an opportunity to handle it.