# Does anyone know why my canvas tag won't show up in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-canvas, excanvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use the HTML5 canvas element in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I did what it said to do but nothing works. I'm using a grid system, but I don't think that's the problem. And I don't think it's my security settings either. Here's my HTML and Javascript if that helps.

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Zack Vivier</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!-- enable HTML5 elements in IE7+8 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- 1140px Grid styles for IE -->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles/1140.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--css3-mediaqueries-js - http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ - Enables media queries in some unsupported browsers-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="hidden">Zack Vivier Home</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="fivecol">
            <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="zack vivier logo"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="sevencol last">
            <nav>
              <h2 class="hidden">Site Navigation</h2>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="info.html">Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelvecol last">
          <div class="lineone"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelvecol last">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4 id="tagLine">Image Number</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <canvas id='showCanvas' width='1022' height='397'>Canvas Not Supported</canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="threecol last">
          <div class="about"><h2>About Me</h2></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelvecol last">
          <div class="linetwo"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="sevencol last">
          <div class="contenthome">
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; My Name is Zack Vivier; currently I am 19</p>
            <p>years old and attend Fanshawe College for Interactive</p>
            <p>Media Design and Production. I am a Designer,</p
            <p>Programmer, Musician, Video Editor, and Animator.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="hidden">footer</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelvecol last">
          <div class="footer">
            <h3>Copyright &copy; 2012 Zack Vivier. All Rights Reserved.</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
// JavaScript Document
var imagePaths = new Array("images/photo_1.png", "images/game_web.jpg", "images/tattoo.jpg");
var whichImage = new Array("Graffti Project", "Game WebSite", "Tattoo Project");
var showCanvas;
var showCanvasCtx;
var imageText;
var currentImage = 0;
var currentImageText = 0;
var img = document.createElement("img");
function init() {
  imageText=document.getElementById('tagLine');
  showCanvas = document.getElementById('showCanvas');
  showCanvasCtx = showCanvas.getContext('2d');
  img.setAttribute('width','1022');
  img.setAttribute('height','397');
  switchImage();
  setInterval(switchImage, 2500);
}
function switchImage() {
  imageText.innerHTML = whichImage[currentImageText++];
  img.setAttribute('src',imagePaths[currentImage++]);
  img.onload = function() {
    if (currentImage >= imagePaths.length) {
      currentImage = 0;
      currentImageText = 0;
    }
    showCanvasCtx.drawImage(img,0,0,1022,397);
  }
  window.onload = init();
```

Comment: Sentences start with a capital letter.

Comment: And I'm takes an apostrophe, and `its` is the genitive form of it, not the contracted form of `it is` and Java has nothing to do with Javascript, and, and, and...

Comment: What make you think IE8 supports the canvas element? See Browser support on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: Emo, first of all w3schools isn't the place for this kind of information, they have been wrong before. And it explicitly says that IE9 has support for canvas, not IE8

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is a HTML5 element which IE8 doesn't supports.
Your doctype is also wrong since you're using HTML5 set it to: "".

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments: IE8 won't support the canvas tag. However there are some plugins that mimic it's behavior. I've used this one once: http://flashcanvas.net/ and it does the job, there's another called http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/. but i have no comment on that one, never used, don't know what to expect.

Just one **note**: the fallbacks will have their limitations, but as far as 2D drawing concerns, I think these will work out for you

Comment: yea i tried excanvas but it didnt work

Comment: I've used flashcanvas for this application http://www.dessosports.com/nl/extra so perhaps you should try this one, and if you have trouble implementing these plugins you can perhaps add this code to your question or make a fiddle?