# Canvas only drawing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/MP4Yg/5/embedded/result/

Heres a plugin I've been working on to create Hub-Spoke diagrams. I've avoided asking any questions pertaining to this so far (gonna go ahead and pat myself on the back for that one) but, I've now hit a roadblock...

My functions are working great but for some reason only in chrome (and partially in opera). I'm using `<canvas>` to draw lines between circles, none of which render outside of chrome. I want this to work in at least IE 8+, and it should work in updated FF and Safari, etc.

I'm also self taught on all of this so any suggestions and feedback on my code would be appreciated, although I'm not sure this is the place for that.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie

Comment: Thanks that helps for IE8, although I'm thinking of just abandoning IE8 and using a simple fallback to display the data. Regardless, IE9, FF and Safari should all be working, any ideas what the deal is?