# Does canvas render markup inside the tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, canvas, svg

I'm creating an application that would preferably use canvas, however I need to support IE8.

I know I can use SVG but I was wondering if I could put the SVG element inside the canvas, but I don't want to load it twice, if you get me

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself ?

Comment: [Are you sure you can use SVG in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie if canvas is what you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to look into canvg.

https://code.google.com/p/canvg/

canvg is a SVG parser and renderer. It takes a URL to a SVG file or the text of an SVG file, parses it in JavaScript, and renders the result on a Canvas element.

Example code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('test').getContext('2d');
ctx.drawSvg('<svg><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" /></svg>', 0 , 0 , 500, 500);
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qDmhV/)