# Send image data to server in IE 8, IE9

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In FF and Chrome we can send image data to server via this code:

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

and then this base 64 string is decoded and extracted on server. I have the issue in IE now. Right now I have the image in "img" control like:

```
<img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg" />
```

I want to send the this image data (not src) to server in IE 8, 9. Can you help me doing the same? Any pointers to achieve it?

Comment: IE8, IE9. Edited the question too.

Comment: i doubt that's going to happen: you can't teach an old dog new tricks...

Comment: Try following
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie

Comment: okay, let's ignore canvas element, is there a way to send image data from image control (<img/>) to server, basically I want to use that data to extract image. I am not talking of image src here.

Answer (score 0):

As you know it is pretty hard to do this without a canvas (not supported in IE8/IE9). What version of ASP.NET is your server? I would think to solve this is by writing a controller action that can take a source `URL` to an image. The action could download the image and convert it to base64, then send it where you need.

Comment: For that I went to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript but that says I have to use "canvas" which is not supported for IE8, IE9

Comment: My intention was to point to the second answer by Sunny which has a solution that will work with those versions of IE!

Comment: From where I will get input data. I just have image and its src.