# canvas in ie8 browsers not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, internet-explorer-8

Html5 canvas not working in ie8 browsers...
can you guys tell me how to fix it...
providing my code below

```
 var animate = function() {
        ctx.width = ctx.width;

        percent += STEP_PERCENT;
        var deg = percent / 100 * deg360;

        drawArc('#aaa', radius, deg360);
        drawArc('#0e728e', radius, deg);
        for (var i = 0, n = Math.floor(deg / deg60); i < n; i++) {
            var from = i * deg30 + deg2;
            var to = from + deg30 - deg2 * 2
            drawArc('#250696', radius, to, from);
        }
        drawArc('#fff', radius - SPINNER_WIDTH, deg360);

        if (percent >= 100) {
            document.getElementById('text').innerText = 'FINISHED';
        } else {
            setTimeout(animate, STEP_DELAY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie

Answer (score 2):

Canvas is not supported in IE8, there is a work around called excanvas https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

that works rather well, but some thing still wont be supported

Comment: I updated in the fiddle but its not working...can you help me with it http://jsfiddle.net/fHmA8/1/