# Read image file and convert to base64 format in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using below jquery which reads the image input from file input and convert into base64 format to display  which is working perfectly fine in googlechrome but not in IE.  I wanted to acheive the same thing in IE. Please help

```
function readImage(input) {
if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
         $('#img').attr( "src", e.target.result );
         $('#base').text( e.target.result );
    };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
  }
 }

$("#asd").change(function(){

   readImage( this );
});
```

Comment: what version of IE? Filereader is supported by 10 and higher.

Comment: @mccainz : 
It is IE8 mccainz

Answer (score 0):

IE only supports FileReader in IE10 and higher.

[Can I use - FileReader](http://caniuse.com/filereader)

Besides that your IE8 will only support 32kb of data for a base64 image source.
You will need to find another approach which involves returning the base64 string explicitly from your server if you are  required to support IE9 and lower. One client side approach would be to extract base64 data from a canvas...

[how-to-upload-an-image-save-it-to-localstorage-and-then-display-it-on-the-next...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-upload-an-image-save-it-to-localstorage-and-then-display-it-on-the-next?rq=1)

Problem with this is IE8 will defeat you again and you will have to go looking for some sort of shim to work around your problem.
[Can I use - Canvas](http://caniuse.com/canvas)
[how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie)

Finally you can try a FileReader polyFill such as

https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader