# IE8 and lower versions those do not support HTML5. How can we implement canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, css3pie

As per requirement implemented canvas in HTML5 and its work , but its not working in IE8 and lower version .

Any solution for that .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie ?

Comment: There is also a Flash based canvas:  http://flashcanvas.net/. IE<9 is dying quickly and perhaps you can just show your your IE<9 visitors a static image and tell them to get the full effects by updating their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of this field but you can start searching a solution with HTML5 canvas polyfill. I found this polyfill for HTML5 after a few searching: https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js

Answer (score 0):

First you will need HTML 5 polyfill for those browsers.
(They dont support HTML5 itself - forget canvas)
https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/   
If you have done that...

There are a couple of libraries that get the canvas running on IE
using flash and java fallback.

Some good ones are ...
http://flashcanvas.net/ (proprietary - paid if commercial)
https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/ (free)

I don't know how well they support all commands.
There might be bugs (known / unknown)...

I'd recommend you to use Raphael instead of Canvas if
you are aiming for cross - browser implementations.

Raphael uses SVG on modern browsers and VML on IE.

I hope you find your solution through this.