# Canvas tag to be used in internet explorer

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have a code where I am using canvas tag and saving the image to png format...this code works fine in chrome browser  but when I try to run this code in internet explorer it doesn't work...I have tried in IE8 as well as IE11...what should be done done to make this code work in IE as well?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What about showing us the code?

Comment: IE8 don't support canvas, if you must have canvas on IE8 check out some of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332501/how-can-i-use-the-html5-canvas-element-in-ie (IE11 should work though, post your code and we can help you figure out why it didn't.)